# Select attribute content XPath

Tags: html, dom, xpath, web

I have an XPath

```
//*[@class]
```

I would like to make an XPath to select the content inside this attribute.

```
<li class="tab-off" id="navList0">
```

So in this case I would like to extract the text "tab-off", is this possible with XPath?

Comment: I have tried //*[@class]/@class it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original `//*[@class]` XPath query returns all elements which have a `class` attribute. What you want is `//*[@class]/@class` to retrieve the attribute itself.

In case you just want the value and not the attribute name try `string(//*[@class]/@class)` instead.

Comment: diff between `//*[@class]/@class` and `string(//*[@class]/@class)` ?

Comment: `//*[@class]/@class` will give you the result..why need string function?

Comment: The 1st query will return the whole node, while the 2nd returns just the node value as text.

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically grabbing the data from an

tag, you can do this:

```
//li[@class]
```

and loop through the result set to find a class with attribute "tab-off". Or

```
//li[@class='tab-off']
```

If you're in a position to hard code.

I assume you have already put your file through an XML parser like a DOMParser. This will make it much easier to extract any other values you may need on a specific tag.

Comment: Well it would need to work for all tags with attribute "class".  So //*[@class]/@class is my solution.  Thanks for the support